# Firefox Web Extension Internationalization Error

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

I've started to develop my first Firefox Web Extension on the 55.0.2 version yesterday. I wanted to add different languages for that extension, so I read about this topic on the official website here: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Internationalization .

However, things are not going as they should, because now whenever I try to load my app with the about:debugging, it keeps popping this error message "There was an error during installation: Extension is invalid".

I've searched a bit what could cause this issue and what I found is completely odd. Whenever I have a folder like "en" or "fr" inside my _locales folder, Firefox keeps showing me that error message up.

I've tried to add a default locale inside my manifest.json to fix it, but no luck with that, it doesn't work. I've tried making my messages.json as simple as possible by just changing the extension name & extension description, no luck.

For a reason I don't understand, those sub folders are preventing me from adding different languages.

Here's my manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "default_locale": "en",
    "name": "__MSG_extensionName__",
    "description": "__MSG_extensionDescription__",
    "version": "1.0",
    "applications": {
        "gecko":{

        }
    },

    "permissions": [
        "contextMenus",
        "activeTab"
    ],

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["ddo.js"]
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Download Destination Organizer"
    }
}
```

Here's my messages.json inside my "en" sub-folder inside _locales:

```
{
  "extensionName": {
    "message": "DDO",
    "description": "Name of the extension."
  },

  "extensionDescription": {
    "message": "Insert description here",
    "description": "Description of the extension."
  }

}
```

Here's my messages.json inside my "fr" sub-folder inside _locales:

```
{
  "extensionName": {
    "message": "DDO",
    "description": "Name of the extension."
  },

  "extensionDescription": {
    "message": "Insérer la description ici.",
    "description": "Description of the extension."
  }

}
```

Comment: How do you install the extension? Do you use the web-ext command line?

Comment: I use the about:debugging page and load the App as a Temp App.

Comment: Are you sure that you have well named the `_locales` folder?

Answer (score 1):

Use the official `web-ext` tool from the Mozilla repository: https://github.com/mozilla/web-ext

It works for me when I run your example with this command (on MacOS):

`web-ext run --firefox`

You can also run it in firefox developer edition with this command:

`web-ext run --firefox /Applications/FirefoxDeveloperEdition.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox`

Moreover, you can run it with the verbose option (`-v`) to see exactly where is the failing issue:

`web-ext run --firefox -v`

Here my architecture (I changed nothing that you provided, I only added the ddo.js file described in the manifest -- the ddo.js file contains a `console.log`):

```
|- _locales
|  |- en
|  |  |- messages.json
|  |
|  |- fr
|  |  |- messages.json
|
|- ddo.js
|- manifest.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading the webextension zipped?

How are you zipping it?

You have to zip it with a `"compatible"` program, I get that error when I zip it by powershell command line using Compress-Archive for example, but if I zip it with the windows `send to -> Compressed (zipped) folder` menu or with 7z default options for zip, then it passes fine.